# Remove Custom Object From Array

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, macos

I would like to remove a custom object of class `A` from an array `[A]()`

I am well aware that this is a well discussed question on SO however there doesn't seem to be a generic and authoritative answer to it, either for beginners or experts.

Example: I have a `FriendRequest` class with a few attributes.

When I accept a `FriendRequest`, it should be removed from `friendRequestArray`.

I'm looking for an answer that aggregates the most common methods and best practices; something along the lines of:

> As of Swift 2.1, there are 3 ways to do this (...)
>
> please don't use `X` as it is deprecated (...)
>
> `Y` is the wrong way to do this" etc.

Comment: Please try to share the structure of your class `FriendRequest` and clarify what exactly you mean with **As of Swift 2.1, there are 3 ways to do this (...) ...** to can help you.

Comment: @VictorSigler The structure of the class is irrelevant to the question. The question stipulates that I am looking for something "along the lines of" what is in markdown. This does not mean that what is in markdown contains _what_ I am looking for, rather it shows _how_ what I'm looking for, looks like.

Comment: Not isn't irrelevant at all, if you see the answer posted below, the class need to implement the `Equatable` protocol to handle the comparison between elements, and if we don't know the elements that compose the class how you compare the elements itself?

Comment: @VictorSigler Instead of downvoting, you really should just read the question. Then you will see how irrelevant it is. The question is a general question about the common methods and best practices of removing a custom object from an array. It is not specific to my case. I am not debugging.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure I understand the question, let's see.

### FriendRequest

You have a `FriendRequest` class like this

```
class FriendRequest {
    let id: String
    init(id: String) {
        self.id = id
    }
}
```

### Let's make it Equatable

```
extension FriendRequest: Equatable {}
func ==(left: FriendRequest, right: FriendRequest) -> Bool {
    return left.id == right.id
}
```

### requests

Now we create 3 `FriendRequest(s)`

```
let request0 = FriendRequest(id: "000")
let request1 = FriendRequest(id: "001")
let request2 = FriendRequest(id: "002")
```

and let's create the `requests` array

```
var requests = [request0, request1, request2]
```

### Removing a request

Now let's say we want to remove `request1`. We need to find the index (if it does exists) and use it to remove an element of the array.

```
if let index = requests.indexOf(request1) {
    requests.removeAtIndex(index)
}
```

That's it

```
requests // [{id "000"}, {id "002"}]
```

Done with Swift 2.1.1 and Xcode Playground 7.2.

Comment: I think your way is fine but he is looking for an answer not using `indexOf` according to his question

Comment: Ok I don't understand the question :D Should my answer have this "format"? `As of Swift 2.1, there are 3 ways to do this (...) please don't use find as it is deprecated (...) indexOf is the wrong way to do this" etc.` Should my answer include the part where **I say** that `indexOf` is the wrong way?? :D

Comment: I think the question is not very clear, but as I understand you need to use something different from `indexOf`